# Always center thumbnails in gallery

Tags: html, css

Here's a quick fiddle I made on topic: http://jsfiddle.net/Z67p4/

So, my question is - if the content is generated dynamically in the future, how do I make thumbnails always centered in the gallery? Even if there are less than four thumbnails in a row they should also be centered  but also should have a gutter in between them.

I tried fiddling with `margin: auto` but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two fixes:

#### Fix One:

Add `text-align:center;` to the container class

#### Fix Two:

Get rid of `display:inline-block;` in the container class.  It is causing your container class to be displayed inline (like text) which left justifies it.

To show this, I put a bg-color on the container class and made it 60% of the screen keeping your original margins.  [As you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/Z67p4/11/), despite having an 'auto' horizontal margin, the div is covering 60% of the screen beginning from the left edge.

---

Three recommendations:

#### Recommendation One:

Remember to add `text-align:left;` if you don't want the text in your thumbnails to be centered.  `text-align` affects all children of the targeted element meaning every child of a div with the `container` class will be centered.

#### Recommendation Two:

Really more of a pet peeve...

Try to find a way to define the size of your content elements (thumbnails) without using percentages.  Your page will be able to scale to different screens through your use of different, carefully-sized elements that will *center* themselves based on the viewing size.  Having elements center and scale may be overkill.

#### Recommendation Three:

Add a minimum width for your container.  This way you won't have to worry about whether your elements could possibly overflow because of a percentage based container.

---

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z67p4/15/) is a version combing the fixes as well as my recommendations.  I have commented each change I made.

Answer (score 3):

Try `text-align:center` on the container

http://jsfiddle.net/Z67p4/9/